# Multiple managed object in one Scada widget

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to present some devices with their measurements on one single SVG file to show a graphical view of a room.

But from what I see, we can't link the properties of multiples devices to one SCADA widget. It seems a bit limited but maybe I miss something?

Comment: You are correct that SCADA has such a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked the feature was added (Cumulocity v7.25).

SCADA widgets can now access properties of multiple devices.